# Adding to Cart with Querystring - Takes me to homepage?

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, php, query

I'm trying to add a product to my cart via query string based on the information on the Magento website.

I've tried the following:

- /checkout/cart/add/product/3887/1/
- /checkout/cart/add/product/3887/1/e8JDefUuLcGdLE1Q (Added Form Key)
- /checkout/cart/add?product=3887&qty=1

The Product ID here is 3887 and it's a Simple product, with no special or custom options.
I'm trying to send it through Ajax but it doesn't get put in the cart and then when I attempt to enter the URL directly I just get redirected to the homepage.

I'm getting the Product ID from a custom page where customers will be able to enter a list of SKU's into 10 input boxes (Quickshop page)

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION for others:**

URL **must** follow this:

```
/checkout/cart/add/product/PRODUCTID/qty/NUMBER/form_key/WSFiE69HmvU854G2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url for adding needs to include a form_key.

```
/checkout/cart/add/product/554/form_key/QOTCSV8HqoLA0K3T/
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I see I've forgotten form_key - I have the Key itself but no label! I'll try now

Comment: Update: I've also noticed I missed out /qty/
I now have: /checkout/cart/add/product/3887/qty/5/form_key/WSFiE69HmvU854G2

Works nicely!