# Is it possible to make a banner add a product to the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, image, addtocart

Is it possible to make it so when an image is click a product is added to the cart?

At the moment , i have tried the below:

```
<?php if ($login && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()==5)
{?>
<div><?php

echo '<img src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/images/basket_banner_v2.png">'; }?>
</div>
```

Which makes sure the correct banner is shown for the group and then displays the image, however i dont know how to make that image add a product tot he cart when it is click or even if it is possible.

I have tried wrapping the image in anchor tags but it just redirects to the cart without doing anything.

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/checkout/cart/add?product=[11341]&qty=[1]">
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I dont know how to make the image clickable so that when it is click a certain product is added to the cart, either by SKU or product ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer through one of after a bit more digging it can be found here:

[I want to use ADD TO CART via URL in Magento 1.8 but don't know which files to change](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/i-want-to-use-add-to-cart-via-url-in-magento-1-8-but-dont-know-which-files-to-c)