# Adding AddToCart link to facebook shopping page

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, facebook

I have a Magento v1.9.2.3 webshop and I'm also adding my products to my Facebook shopping page.

I thought I could use the form action url from my webshop as the payment url in FB shopping: my-webshop/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2NyYXB3ZWJzaG9wLm5sL3N0ZXJyZW5iZWVsZC1rbmlwdmVsbGVuLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/5130/form_key/bO1glkQ2GyvpRd7m/

But after reading I (and trying) I understand the form_key is changed after every cache clear/refresh (which we do very regularly).
So I need a more flexible solution.

How can I solve this? I can't imagine I'm the first to try this. Should I create a new php page that will do this or ... ?

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT**

I created a new php page in the root of my webshop and added these lines:

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(5130);
 echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, array('qty'=>1, 'form_key'=>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
```

The resulting url is `my-webshop/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2NyYXB3ZWJzaG9wLm5sL0FkZFRvQ2FydC5waHA,/product/5130/form_key/lPCvzei32zLtxqxp/qty/1/` but according to the form url it should be `my-webshop/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2NyYXB3ZWJzaG9wLm5sL3NhbGUvc3RlcnJlbmJlZWxkLWtuaXB2ZWxsZW4uaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/product/5130/form_key/kqe8DtKacPrJzjgN/`
Notice the difference of the `form_key` ?!?!?

The resulting URL is not working, but the form url is. So this is not a working solution.

Found something else and added these lines of code:

```
try {     
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(5130);

    $parameter = array('product' => '5130',
                'qty' => '1',
                'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
        );       

    $request = new Varien_Object();
    $request->setData($parameter);
    $cart->addProduct($product, $request);
    $cart->save();     
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
    echo 'product added<br>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

`product added` was printed but when I go to my cart it is still empty.
So this is not working either.

I would really much appreciate if someone would help me out.

Comment: Sadly no answer. I did some more looking and found dozen other similar questions with no working solution either. I'll update my post with some code I tried so far (without any luck)

Comment: Not sure if my answer from 4 years ago is still valid for 1.9, but you can give it a try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/37781/146

Comment: Create a controller action on which you can receive the product sku or id and add the product to cart programatically. And create a url like abc.com/frontname/actionname/id/product_id and put this url in your facebook page. If you want me to create a module then I can write an answer. Let me know if this logic helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did see the controller suggestion before, but I find it a bit complicated for my skills ;)

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281786/add-product-to-cart-outside-of-magento-external-script
Which I merged with what I already had. And the trick seems to be to call `$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");` then you get the correct form-key.

Here's my complete script, which seems to work:

```
/* Configuration */
define('WEBSTORE_NAME','default');

$productId = !isset($_GET['id']) ? '' : $_GET['id'];
if(empty($productId)) {
    // "no product-id found";
    redirect("my-webshop", 301);
}    

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281786/add-product-to-cart-outside-of-magento-external-script
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app(WEBSTORE_NAME);     
umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);   
$url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, array('qty'=>1, 'form_key'=>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));     

redirect($url);

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
```

And I call it as this: `my-webshop/AddToCart.php?id=5130`

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little late, but you should be able to do this.

> yourdomain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=sku&qty=1

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I tried that but that doesn't work (anymore). Apparently after Magento v1.7 the form_key is needed which changes very regularly.

Comment: We are in magento 1.9 and im pretty sure it works fine. :)