# How to create a "add to cart link" on a website that uses Magento?

Tags: addtocart, link

I want to know how to create a "add to cart link" on a website that uses Magento.
A retailer’s website uses Magento, I want create add to cart urls to post on my instagram people could directly check out.
So far I got to this:
https://domain/checkout/cart/delete/id/product/
Also i found this in the page source code:

> form_key/AGXbCT8XKMhJVixv/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYWZldy1zdG9yZS5jb20vZGUvY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC8,/

Comment: This answer can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/37781/51803
<br> Regards, Pablo